# Put data into mongodb's query in Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a query in Expressjs like this :

```
 collection.find({location : {$near: [106.688227,10.774266], $maxDistance: 0.01}},function(e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
```

It works well but when I get the parameter from the request to put it in the query , it does not work :

```
router.get('/locations', function(req, res) {
    var lat = req.param('lat');
    var lng = req.param('lng');
    var radius = req.param('radius');
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('location');
    collection.find({location : {$near: [lng,lat], $maxDistance: radius}},function(e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });

});
```

I how can replace "lng","lat" and "radius" into the query?

Thanks.

Comment: Several tips: 1. Try putting console.log statements to see that the lat/lng values are indeed what you expect them to be. 2. Try use the `parseFloat` function, since the values you get from the request are probably strings, and it could be that the $near operator expects numbers.

Comment: Hi Protostome, I had tried your tips before asking, but it does not work, ....

Comment: OK, try using the following structure: `{location: { $near : { $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ lng, lat ] }, $maxDistance: radius } } } }`

Comment: it does not work , too....